# How can Pepper Robot dialog execute javascript function?

Tags: javascript, pepper

I am developing Pepper robot application. It supports audio and tablet input simultaneously. So when option on tablet is choosed it will use ALDialog to forceinput message to Pepper dialog and then i want Pepper dialog to change pepper tablet view. I tried using ALMemory and then javascript to subscribe to it. But it seems that i can not find the event. For example if i created $show_index_view=1 in dialog. Then how can i register that event to it so it will then know what to listen to in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a tutorial that I implemented on a git for [connecting choregraphe and a web page](http://protolab.aldebaran.com/protolab/tutorials/tree/master/ConnectionHtmlChoregraphe).

So your web page is connected to an event and you can send a message thanks to ALMemory.raiseEvent.
For more details, see [this web page](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/core/almemory-api.html#almemory-api).